# Check Textbox text is excel valid formula and use that function to calculate in VBA without storing any value in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, validation, textbox

I am trying to learn EXCEL VBA. One of the tasks I am stuck with is how to verify `textbox1.text` is valid excel formula. I tried `Worksheetfunction.isfunction(userform1. text1.text)` but it is giving error. My objective is to validate the `userform1.text1.text = valid` EXCEL function (say x^2 or sin(x)). If valid then use `Evaluate` function/method to calculate the value. Tried text as follows :

```
if worksheetfunction.isformula(userform1.text1.text) = true then A(i).value = worksheetfuntion.evaluate(userform1.text1.text,"x", B(i))
```

A and B are value arrays as varient
I am not able to understand what the error is, any help?

Comment: `.IsFormula` needs a range as a parameter and answers, whether the range stores a formula or not. Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.worksheetfunction.isformula). Try to use [IsError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function) instead.

Answer (score 1):

a) `worksheetfunction.isformula` expects a Range as parameter - with other words, you can check if a cell contains a formula, but not if a string is a formula. You get a type mismatch error if you try (because a string and a range are not compatible types).

b) WorksheetFunction has no `evaluate`-method, you need to use `Application.Evaluate` (you can omit the `Application`)

c) `evaluate` result in an error (Error 2015) if the string you pass cannot be evaluated (because it contains an invalid formula). You can check if the result with the function `IsError`. However, be aware that there might be cases where the formula itself is valid, but the result is an error (eg your formula is `"A1/A2"` and cell A2 contains 0, you get a *Division by 0* error).

d) `evaluate` will evaluate the string with and without leading `=` while a formula in Excel always starts with the `=`.

```
Dim formula as String, checkValue As Variant 
formula = userform1.text1.text
checkValue = Application.Evaluate(formula)
If not IsError(checkValue) Then 
    A(i).value = checkValue
Else
   MsgBox formula & " is not a valid formula"
End If
```

Comment: ad b) It is worth noting that there is no evaluate-method of `WorksheetFunction`, but that you can use a worksheet related [evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) (e.g. `ws.Evaluate(...)`) which has the benefit that it interpretes formula range indications without further qualification as range of this worksheet without need of additional prefixing via "!" @FunThomas

Comment: Thanks for the hint. To be honest, I am not really familiar with `Evaluate` at all, in all my > 20 years of Excel/VBA, I cannot remember that I ever used it.

Comment: Dear Thomas, Thanks for the elaborate feedback. I tried to use the Evaluate without prefix worksheetfunction. However, it is giving me "Wrong number of arguments (Error 450)" or invalid property. What is the meaning of "not IsError(res)" Is res some another variable we need to define or it is already some boolean? as true/ false? Sorry for may be basic uestions, I am a new learner in VBA programming. Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake when copying my test code to the answer. Replace `res` with `checkValue`. However, I don't understand your other error. Try to use `Application.Evaluate(formula)` - see my updated code.

Comment: @FunThomas You can't use IsError for this.  For an invalid String, Evaluate will throw a runtime error, which you handle with an Error Handler (On Error ...).  (If the string is valid, the formula can return and Error Value)